# ng2-smart-table is compatible with SystemJS

Tags: angular, smart-table

I'm trying to import this module via systemjs with this configuration:

```
map = {
    'ng2-smart-table': 'js/node_modules/ng2-smart-table'
  };

packages = {
'ng2-smart-table': {main: 'build/ng2-smart-table.js',defaultJSExtension: 'js'}  };
```

And I'm getting error

> http://localhost:8000/js/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/lib.js
>   404 (Not Found)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

don't waste your time on this, it totally doesn't work with systemJS.